# New crashlytics (com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics) not working anymore on non-Google Play devices?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I updated from the Fabric Crashlytics to the new com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics beta yesterday on two of my apps.

Unlike the old one, now Crashlytics doesn't seem to work anymore on devices that doesn't have Google Play services (like for example Amazon devices). Crashes with a "FirebaseCrashlytics component is not present" when calling most methods of the new API.

Some Firebase modules like Analytics are working on Amazon devices for example, I thought it would be the same here.

Does someone have more information on this or know where I could ask for more information about if it's temporarily or a permanent thing?

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced an issue with the beta release even though I use a Samsung device for development. My app simply doesn't connect to Crashlytics.

Google published a [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android) a few days ago.
I checked and did all this steps but the app still doesn't work, so for now I rather stay with the previous working version. 
In the future I will track the site linked above to keep myself up-to-date.